# Safely writing to and reading from the same file with multiple processes on Linux and Mac OS X

Tags: file, file-io, io, inode

I have three processes designed to run constantly in both Linux and Mac OS X environments. One process (the Downloader) downloads and stores a local copy of a large XML file every 30 seconds. Two other processes (the Workers) use the stored XML file for input. Each Worker starts and runs at random times. Since the XML file is big, it takes a long time to download. The Workers also take a long time to read and parse it.

What is the safest way to setup the processes so the Downloader doesn't clobber the stored file while the Workers are trying to read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Linux and Mac OS X machines that use [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) based file systems, use temporary files to store the data while its being downloaded (and is an incomplete state). Once the download is complete, move the temporary file into its final location with an atomic action.

For a little more detail, there are two main things to watch out for when one process (e.g. Downloader) writes a file that's actively read by other processes (e.g. Workers):

1. Make sure the Workers don't try to read the file before the Downloader has finished writing it.
2. Make sure the Downloader doesn't alter the file while the Workers are reading it.

Using temporary files accommodates both of these points.

For a more specific example, when the Downloader is actively pulling the XML file, have it write to a temporary location (e.g. 'data-storage.tmp') on the same device/disk* where the final file will be stored. Once the file is completely downloaded and written, have the Downloader move it to its final location (e.g. 'data-storage.xml') via an [atomic (aka linearizable)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) rename command like bash's `mv`.

* *Note that the reason the temporary file needs to be on the same device as the final file location is to ensure the inode number stays the same and the rename can be done atomically.*

This methodology ensures that while the file is being downloaded/written the Workers won't see it since it's in the .tmp location. Because of the way renaming works with inodes, it also make sure that any Worker that opened the file continues to see the old content even if a new version of the data-storage file is put in place.

Downloader will point 'data-storage.xml' to a new inode number when it does the rename, but the Worker will continue to access 'data-storage.xml' from the previous inode number thereby continuing to work with the file in that state. At the same time, any Worker that opens a new copy 'data-storage.xml' after Downloader has done the rename will see contents from the new inode number since it's now what is referenced directly in the file system. So, two Workers can be reading from the same filename (data-storage.xml) but each will see a different (and complete) version of the contents of the file based on which inode the filename was pointed to when the file was first opened.

To see this in action, I created a simple set of example scripts that demonstrate this functionality on [github](https://github.com/alanwsmith/examples--multiprocess-file-sharing). They can also be used to test/verify that using a temporary file solution works in your environment.

---

*An important note is that it's the file system on the particular device that matters. If you are using a Linux or Mac machine but working with a FAT file system (for example, a usb thumb drive), this method won't work.*